# PYQT5: Using a for loop or something else to create many QLabel/QPushButton of the same type

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm using PYQT5 to create a GUI to display buttons and labels, and I want an efficient way to create many of the same type but with different names. Currently, I have to copy paste the same code to make each individual button, so my code is unnecessarily long.

Here's what it looks like currently for 8 buttons:

```
def setupUi(self, HomeWindow):

        if not HomeWindow.objectName():
            HomeWindow.setObjectName(u"HomeWindow")

        mydb = mc.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password='mhm',
            database="cinedeck")
        

        cur = mydb.cursor()
        q = "SELECT movie_name, movie_poster from movies"
        cur.execute(q)
        res = cur.fetchall()

        self.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(HomeWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(-20, 10, 291, 101))
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(r"CineDeck\assets\logo.svg"))
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1920, 150))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 1)")
        self.label_7 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setObjectName(u"label_7")
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 19200, 9300))
        self.label_7.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(r"CineDeck\assets\pure-white-background-85a2a7fd.jpg"))
        self.horizontalWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalWidget.setObjectName(u"horizontalWidget")
        self.horizontalWidget.setGeometry(QRect(330, 40, 561, 41))
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.label_5 = QLabel(self.horizontalWidget)
        self.label_5.setObjectName(u"label_5")
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.label_3 = QLabel(self.horizontalWidget)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(u"label_3")
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)

        self.label_4 = QLabel(self.horizontalWidget)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(u"label_4")
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)

        self.label_6 = QLabel(self.horizontalWidget)
        self.label_6.setObjectName(u"label_6")
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_6)

        self._8b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._8b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._8b.setGeometry(QRect(20, 530, 230, 50))
        self.label_8 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QRect(20, 190, 230, 326))
        self.label_8.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[0][1])).scaled(230, 326))
        self._9b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._9b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._9b.setGeometry(QRect(380, 530, 230, 50))
        self.label_9 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_9.setObjectName(u"label_9")
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QRect(380, 190, 230, 326))
        self.label_9.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[1][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))

        self._10b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._10b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._10b.setGeometry(QRect(740, 530, 230, 50))
        self.label_10 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_10.setObjectName(u"label_10")
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QRect(740, 190, 230, 326))
        self.label_10.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[2][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))
        

        self._11b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._11b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._11b.setGeometry(QRect(1100, 530, 230, 50))
        self.label_11 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_11.setObjectName(u"label_11")
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QRect(1100, 190, 230, 326))
        self.label_11.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[2][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))

        self._12b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._12b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._12b.setGeometry(QRect(1460, 530, 230, 50))
        self.label_12 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_12.setObjectName(u"label_12")
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QRect(1460, 190, 230, 326))
        self.label_12.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[2][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))

        self._13b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._13b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._13b.setGeometry(QRect(20, 930, 230, 50))
        self.label_13 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName(u"label_13")
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QRect(20, 590, 230, 326))
        self.label_13.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[3][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))

        self._13b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._13b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._13b.setGeometry(QRect(380, 930, 230, 50))
        self.label_13 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName(u"label_13")
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QRect(380, 590, 230, 326))
        self.label_13.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[4][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))
        
        self._13b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._13b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._13b.setGeometry(QRect(740, 930, 230, 50))
        self.label_13 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName(u"label_13")
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QRect(740, 590, 230, 326))
        self.label_13.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[5][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))
        

        self._13b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._13b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._13b.setGeometry(QRect(1100, 930, 230, 50))
        self.label_13 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName(u"label_13")
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QRect(1100, 590, 230, 326))
        self.label_13.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[6][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))
        
        self._13b = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self._13b.setObjectName(u"label_8")
        self._13b.setGeometry(QRect(1460, 930, 230, 50))
        self.label_13 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_13.setObjectName(u"label_13")
        self.label_13.setGeometry(QRect(1460, 590, 230, 326))
        self.label_13.setPixmap(
            QPixmap("{}".format(res[7][1])).scaled(230, 325).scaled(230, 325))


        HomeWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.horizontalWidget.raise_()

        self.label_8.raise_()
        self.label_8.raise_()
        self.label_9.raise_()
        self.label_10.raise_()
        self._8b.raise_()
        self._9b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
        #self._10b.raise_()
```

I have to create around 40-50 buttons, and they have the same properties. They only differ in names and the positioning in the UI (setGeometry(QtCore.QRect()). What's the best way to create this many buttons without just copy and pasting the same code 50 times and changing the name.

I'm not sure how a for loop would work, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. you don't need to create instance attributes (`self.whatever`) for all widgets, you can eventually decide to add them to a list or dict (which, instead, *must* be an instance attribute) in case you need to access them; 2. don't use fixed geometries, use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html); 3. don't edit pyuic files, as it's a terrible practice, instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Noted. Could you suggest how to make multiple buttons(around 50 in this case) using a for loop or any other method. I've tried using a for loop but I've done it wrong and im not so sure how it would work.

Comment: Then show us your attempt so that we can tell you what issue(s) it has.